# How to move iocage jails from one ZFS pool to another?

Tags: freebsd, truenas, jail

What is the process to move iocage and all its jails from one ZFS pool to another?

I've tried the process from this post: https://www.ixsystems.com/community/threads/how-to-move-jails-between-pools.72593/post-502840

i.e. `iocage export` each jail, activate the new pool, then `iocage import`. That isn't successful:

```
$ iocage start syncthing
No default gateway found for ipv6.
* Starting syncthing
  + Started OK
  + Using devfs_ruleset: 6
  + Configuring VNET FAILED
  jexec: execvp: ifconfig: No such file or directory
  jexec: execvp: ifconfig: No such file or directory

Stopped syncthing due to VNET failure
```

FreeNAS 11.3

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To move iocage from `/mnt/OLD/iocage` to `/mnt/NEW/iocage`:

#### Export jails

```bash
iocage stop JAILNAME
iocage export JAILNAME
```

This creates a dated `.zip` of the jail in `/mnt/OLD/iocage/images`.

#### Set up new pool

Use the FreeNAS jails GUI or `iocage activate /mnt/NEW` to activate iocage on the new pool.
Ensure that the new activation has the iocage release(s) used by your jails. Use
`iocage fetch` to install them. See each jail's `fstab` to see which release it expects.

#### Import jails

Copy the exported jail .zips to where iocage will look for them:

```
cp /mnt/OLD/iocage/images/* /mnt/NEW/iocage/images
```

Import:

```
iocage import JAILNAME
```

Note it's the jail name, not the filename of the zip.

#### Fix mountpoints and fstab

Any mount points in the jail, particularly the ones provided by iocage, will point at `/mnt/OLD` and cause the jail to not start with the VNET error in the question. These have to be manually fixed.

Edit `/mnt/NEW/iocage/jails/JAILNAME/fstab` and replace instances of `/mnt/OLD` with `/mnt/NEW` as appropriate. For simple jails `:%s/OLD/NEW/g` in vi will do the trick.

For example, the first three lines of the `fstab` created by the Syncthing plugin looks like this:

```
/mnt/OLD/iocage/releases/11.3-RELEASE/root/bin  /mnt/OLD/iocage/jails/syncthing/root/bin    nullfs  ro  0   0 # Added by iocage on 2020-04-17 00:16:34
/mnt/OLD/iocage/releases/11.3-RELEASE/root/boot /mnt/OLD/iocage/jails/syncthing/root/boot   nullfs  ro  0   0 # Added by iocage on 2020-04-17 00:16:35
/mnt/OLD/iocage/releases/11.3-RELEASE/root/lib  /mnt/OLD/iocage/jails/syncthing/root/lib    nullfs  ro  0   0 # Added by iocage on 2020-04-17 00:16:35
```

Each `/mnt/OLD` needs to be replaced with `/mnt/NEW`.

#### Done

```
iocage start JAILNAME
```

Comment: "Ensure that the new activation has the iocage release(s) used by your jails. Use iocage fetch to install them. See each jail's fstab to see which release it expects." You can type `iocage fetch` and it will populate a list of available releases. Perhaps add to take note of the releases at the beginning by running `iocage list`.